# how can i Deploy my web app (with JSP pages) in a intranet server

Tags: java, jsp, server

i have just created a web project that contains a bunch of jsp and html pages.i need to know how to Deploy them(or provide access) to client computers using a single server(intranet) and where do i need to install JRE because jsp have java code and sql queries in them which interacts with mysql database.

Comment: You've created a web project without knowing how to deploy and run it?

Comment: Yes, i know how to run it on local computer..but i have no idea about deploying it for multi users on a server....

Comment: Well, then you'll be spending a while getting to understand how the servers work.

Comment: yup..any suggestions about websites where i can learn those??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to install a J2EE container into your intranet and deploy your `war` file on it.

You can easily do this for example using [Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/) Tomcat, but there is a lot of other products, free or not, on the market.

Comment: am sorry i might be bugging bugging you....i know abt JRE, JDK but this is the first time i came across J2EE container....i googled it but i couldn't find any installation guide or page, can you provide me with a link??

Comment: So, i just need to do the same thing on the server which i did on my local computer while developing the project??

Comment: Yes you need to build a `war` file and deploy it into the container.

Comment: i already have my war file. i just need to know the required softwares(like tomcat ) to be installed in intranet server so that other users can make use of the application....no offence but i think eclipse is a development tool...

Comment: ok here you have evething : install, deploy and run a war within a standalone tomcat...

Comment: so i don't need any java related software??, am asking this because my jsp has java code in it..

Comment: thanks ...i was litle bit worried it might need jdk because of the presence of javacode and sql queries .......

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple ! Create its war file using any build tools like maven or ant and deploy it on tomcat server and start your server.